# Midori - remove "search with..." option showing in address bar when typing an address

Tags: midori

I love this little speedy browser, however, I do not always find it easy to configure.

Anyone knows how to modify Midori's configuration to remove the "search with" and "open tabs" lines from the address bar when one types an address? The history is sufficient for me. Actually getting only the bookmarks would be even better. Is that possible?
Thanks,

Comment: In case you don't get an answer here, another resource is https://answers.launchpad.net/midori. The Midori dev monitors that site and responds to questions. If you ask over there and get a satisfactory answer, don't forget to come back here and answer your own question. It's totally acceptable.